# SQL Server Identity won't auto increment with input

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to send data to the SQL Server database that has an `ID` primary key setup with an `Identity` to increment.

From what I've read so far, most people had the issue with including an `Id` property being added in their command code which isn't necessary. Mine doesn't have that so I figured this would work but I still get an error message stating the DB table doesn't allow null for ID. Since I'm using Identity, shouldn't SQL fill that column in automatically?

I've read that in the model you have to use `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` but still it's not running.

Model

```
public class EventModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Event type")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please give an event type.")]
    public EventType EventType { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please give an event title.")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please give a date and time.")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Location")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please give a location")]
    public string Location { get; set; }
    #nullable enable
    public string? Company { get; set; }

}
```

DAL

```
internal bool AddEvent(EventModel eventModel)
{
        // Connect to the database
        string connStr = configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnString") ;
        using SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        conn.Open();

        // Command
        string query = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Event] ([EventType], [Title], [Date], [Location], [Company])" +
                       " VALUES (@EventType, @Title, @Date, @Location, @Company)";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventType", eventModel.EventType);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", eventModel.Title);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", eventModel.Date);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", eventModel.Location);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company", eventModel.Company);

        // Query DB
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();

        // Close Connection
        conn.Close();
        return true;
}
```

Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Event] 
(
    [Id]        INT         NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [EventType] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Title]     VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Date]      DATE        NOT NULL,
    [Time]      VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    [Location]  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Company]   VARCHAR(50) NULL,
);
```

Server Manager

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Event]
(
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EventType] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Time] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Location] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Company] [varchar](50) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: As a side note: is there a reason that your `Time` column is not of type `TIME`?

Comment: Are you *sure* the error message is about the `ID` column? Please copy/paste the actual error message.

Comment: I'll change the type to Time

Comment: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'GopherDirtDB.dbo.Event'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Comment: It looks like it the `CREATE` in the question is not consistent with the actual definition. Please verify its definition by doing Script Table as >> CREATE. You shoudn't be getting that error if it's really defined as you've shown.

Comment: A beginner question here... How do I verify it's definition by doing the Script Table as >> CREATE? Everything I'm typing that resembles that is getting errors

Comment: In SQL Server Management Studio, right-click on the dbo.Event table. The menu will have "Script Table as", which has a sub-menu with various statements such as "CREATE To" and then a final sub-menu with New Query Window, File, or Clipboard. Select New Query Window and compare that to what's in the question.

Comment: `DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)` only applies to Entity Framework DbSets. Since you are using straight ADO, the way you decorate your model is irrelevant. It doesn't explain your problem, but it should narrow down your scope.

Comment: I added the Server Management code above. I'm not sure what to look for in this. There is however a red underline under `[dbo].[Event]` . It says "there is already an object named 'Event' in the database", but there isnt.

Comment: Well there you go. Your table doesn't actually have an identity column.

Comment: Your attention should be drawn to this line: `[Id] [int] NOT NULL,` which shows that you *don't* have the `IDENTITY` property applied to the `Id` column.

Comment: Also, your `Date` column's type is `nchar(10)`, not `date`. You'll want to fix that, too.